# Any way to make time interval not clickable in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want time intervals, occupied by events, to be not clickable. If I just set event property `editable` to `false`, it does not help: I am still able to click near that event. Any way to make all the time interval, occupied by the event not clickable? **Maybe somehow stretch its width to cover the whole day (actually, this would be a desirable behaviour)?**

Comment: have you got an example.. i cannot really imagine the problem you can use this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/7MTdn/  it has fullcalender laoded. Just alter and save it  ill try to help

Comment: I've changed the code there to the one, I'm using (valuable part). The url `/api/calendar/busy/time` returns a json with events. My calendar displays those events correctly, but it opens a popup if I click on the day near those events. Instead, I want that time to be completely busy: clicking only works if you click on part of the day, that does not have a calendar entry already.

Comment: in which view must this be? in month/week/day agenda? I will try to conjur something up - basically if there is an event on a day then you dont want any click to work.. yea? i suppose so

Comment: I nearly got- you going to have use some clever detection method that i will explain later. i already lodged a bug/feature with the writter of FC and suggested he implements this.. he is thinking about it.. but shortly i will have a solution for you..

Comment: Is that what you wanted or did you want it work on week view with the time??

Comment: I just want that particular time, occupied by the event to be not clickable. All the other time intervals should be clickable.

Comment: Oh - right.. i thought it was something like that.. will have to retweak it .. that is a bit more complex. Will see later

Comment: Hello Can you look at this fiddle and set it up the way you want it- because i am not sure the data you are using and the intervals? http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/DarVR/ - and save it by pressing update.

Comment: Hello. That is almost what I wanted. The only problem is that if there are no events for the day, it is not clickable at all.

Comment: Well - if there are no events-- the script wont fire.. so that means you can add anything you want?! Right? So if nothing happens that means you can just add whatever you want on any time on the whole day. Its pretty logical. But.... I added a handler that if nothing is there it will fire another logical part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will fire if a day is occupied by an event. So in theory you can block a click by doing return false; in that logic.

http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/2QAY4/

The code that does the magic needs jquery. and you need this piece of code.

```
  dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

    if ($('div.fc-event').length > 0) {
        //
        var containerD = $(this).offset();
        var containerH = $(this).height();
        var mousex = jsEvent.pageX;

        $('div.fc-event').each(function(index) {
            var offset = $(this).offset();

            if (((offset.left + $(this).outerWidth()) > mousex && offset.left < mousex) && ((offset.top > containerD.top) && (offset.top < (containerD.top + containerH)))) {

                alert($(this).html());
                //This will only fire if an empty space is clicked
                //This will not fire if an event is clicked on a day
            }
        });

    }
    else {
        //Put code here to do things if no events on a day
        alert('There are no events on this day');
    }
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can stretch the events to the full height of a day, using the following CSS:

```
.fc-event-skin { height: 60px; }
```

But I would call that a workarround.

fullCalendar is designed to display multiple events on a day. Hence the bars are small enough to display overlapping events.

A better solution for a booking system would be a calendar that does not support overlapping events. Unfortunately there is none I could recommend.

Comment: I get it: I'll try to change it's width in the same way.

Comment: wont work.. because you will still be able to click on the number of the day and the click will go through  and aorund the edges sometimes... not very great advise. The events are not children of the table but overlaid div elements calculated by x and y coordinates in the jscript of FC... makes thing a bit tricky sometimes. If the calender is resized your static 60px will not work any more....

Comment: I know you wrote "width", but given your example it seamed you wanted to strech the height